# dump does not work with pigrunner

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

Following is my code which runs pigrunner and pigstats:

```
    String[] args = {"abc.pig"};
    PigStats stats = PigRunner.run(args,null);

    System.out.println("Stats : " + stats.getReturnCode());

    OutputStats os = stats.result("B");

    Iterator<Tuple> it = os.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        Tuple t = it.next();
        System.out.println(t.getAll());
    }
```

Contents of abc.pig

```
A = load 'Courses' using PigStorage(' ');
B = foreach A generate $0 as id;
dump B;
```

I get the correct output but it is followed by this exception Stacktrace with root cause

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/tmp/temp-221133443/tmp1478461116
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:235)
  at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigFileInputFormat.listStatus(PigFileInputFormat.java:37)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:252)
  at org.apache.pig.impl.io.ReadToEndLoader.init(ReadToEndLoader.java:154)
  at org.apache.pig.impl.io.ReadToEndLoader.<init>(ReadToEndLoader.java:116)
  at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.OutputStats.iterator(OutputStats.java:148)
  at org.apache.jsp.result_jsp._jspService(result_jsp.java:86)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Now the same code works without an error if I replace the DUMP with a STORE.

Can some please explain me what is going on ?

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 3):

In case of dump Pig stores the output at a *temporary* location, e.g: hdfs://localhost/tmp/temp797130848/tmp1101984728
(have a look `pig.map.output.dirs` in your job's config.xml)

[PigRunner.run()](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/PigRunner.html#run%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigProgressNotificationListener%29) calls [GruntParser.processDump(String alias)](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/tools/grunt/GruntParser.html#processDump%28java.lang.String%29) at some point of the process which iterates through the result tuples and prints them out to the console:

```
Iterator<Tuple> result = mPigServer.openIterator(alias);
while (result.hasNext())
{
  Tuple t = result.next();
  System.out.println(TupleFormat.format(t));
}
```

After this, but before returning, it also calls [FileLocalizer.deleteTempFiles()](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/impl/io/FileLocalizer.html#deleteTempFiles%28%29) which deletes this temporary directory.

Now you want to return the result of alias **B**.
[OutputStats](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/tools/pigstats/OutputStats.html)'s iterator tries to open the temporary file again to loop over the tuples as `PigRunner.run()` did it before.
But the problem is that this file doesn't exist anymore, therefore your get the exception.

So I'd suggest you to remove the code after `System.out.println("Stats : " + stats.getReturnCode());` since you already have the dump printed out.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation, in my case I solved it by passing a PigProgressNotificationListener to the PigRunner and when task completed, I got an OutputStats object containing the output.